# Set to public an implementation file (.m or .mm) inside framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

The same way a header file can be set to public in the target membership when creating a framework, is it possible to do the same thing with an implementation file?
I know it's not the normal thing to do: leaving an implementation file as public within a framework. But it would accelerate the development process a lot for debugging.

This is where I set it for the header file:
[image]

While this is the implementation file:
[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Objective-C, the methods in the implementation file are private by default.  You have no other choice but to expose these methods in a public interface in the header.